# Failed to transform class with name org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache. Reason: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key class is frozen

Tags: java, hadoop, powermockito

Getting java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key class is frozen.

```
Java               : 11
JVM vendor name    : Oracle Corporation
JVM vendor version : 11.0.7+8-LTS
JVM name           : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
JVM version        : 11.0.7+8-LTS
JVM info           : mixed mode
OS name            : Windows 10
OS version         : 10.0
```

Using `Hadoop` client version 3.1.0 and Power mockito version 1.7.4

Please help me out.